# Proof that a least upper bound and a greatest upper bound exist

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that set $X$ is nonempty and bounded. Set $X$ is a subset of the real numbers. 
Then both a least upper bound and a greatest lower bound exist. How do I prove this? I am completely at a loss, and I don't even know where to get started. Help, please.

Comment: Is $X$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 1):

$X \subset \mathbb{R}$. It is a property of $\mathbb{R}$ that the **Least Upper Bound Axiom** holds. The least upper bound axiom states that any nonempty, bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a least upper bound.

So $X$ has a least upper bound. Now we'll do the greatest lower bound: Consider the set $-X = \{-x | x \in X\}$. Again, by the LUB property, it has a least upper bound $L$. Then $-L$ is the greatest lower bound for $X$.

Another way to prove the existence of the greatest lower bound of $X$ is to let $B$ be the set of all lower bounds for $X$. So $B \subset \mathbb{R}$. $B$ is bounded above, so its supremum will be the greatest lower bound for $X$.